# Sending value from escrow contract address with transfer function

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js, metamask

I want to call transferMoney() function which should send value (requests[_id].value) to an address address(uint160(requests[_id].provider)) with the transfer function of solidity. When I call this function via my DApp-Frontend using MetaMask, first I get the confirmation but the transaction gots reverted by the EVM. On etherscan, I see the status = fail. My aim is to send value from contract owner to another account.

What could cause the problem?

Here is the transaction hash on etherscan ropsten testnet: 0x30cef6bc33a25aeb4693a7c463ddf5dd597e0bd2c2ceb47feb38f29599feb4aa

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract PrinterMarketplace {
    uint256 public requestCount = 0;
    uint balance;
    address payable escrow = msg.sender;

    mapping(uint256 => Request) public requests;
    struct Request {
        uint256 id;
        string fileName;
        string fileHash;
        address payable client;
        address payable provider;
        string price;
        uint256 value;
        string status;
    }
    
    function purchaseOffer(
        uint256 _id,
        address payable _client,
        address payable _provider,
        string memory _fileHash
    ) public payable{
        requests[_id].status = "purchased";
        requests[_id].value = msg.value;
        emit OrderEvent(_id, _fileHash, _client, _provider, requests[_id].status);
        escrow.transfer(msg.value);
    }
    
    function transferMoney(
        uint256 _id
        ) public {
        address(uint160(requests[_id].provider)).transfer(requests[_id].value);
        requests[_id].status = "paid";
        }
}
```

Comment: Does the receiving contract have a fallback function? Otherwise it will be unable to receive ether this way. You need either a named 'payable' function that you call, or else a fallback function. 

Edit: I just re-read your question, it sounds like you're sending to an address, not a contract. I'll leave my comment just in case.

Comment: I don't have a fallback function. I want to send from contract address to another address (not contract). Something like this: receiver.transfer(address(this).balance). But I dont want to send the whole balance of the contract rather a part of it, which should be represented in request[index].value